# Erro ao salvar imagem em diretório com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

Fiz uma página que administração de um site que é responsável por incluir novos advogados em um 'bootstrap carousel'. Em minha máquina funciona perfeitamente, mas no servidor é impossível salvar a imagem que é carregada.

Vou explicar:
A imagem não é salva no banco de dados com BLOB nem nada do tipo. A imagem é salva em diretório dentro do servidor, e os dados do formulário são gravados no banco. A referência que fica salva no banco é o caminho físico da imagem, como "../../imagens-advogados/imagem_001.jpg".

Eu suspeito que seja um problema de permissão ao diretório. Eu tenho um droplet na DigitalOcean, que usa Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Rodo o PHP em um servidor apache2 e o banco de dados é o MySql.

Abaixo, o código que uso para os dados do formulário e retornar a mensagem de sucesso/erro:

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['USER']) {
    header('Location: index.php?erro=3');
    $id = session_id();
}

require_once('../classes/DAO.php');
require_once("../config.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$atuation = $_POST['atuation'];
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
$graduacao = $_POST['graduacao'];
$language = $_POST['language'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$cel = $_POST['cel'];

$upload_foto = false;

if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $nome = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    $extensao = pathinfo($nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao)) {
        $novoNome = uniqid(time()) . '.' . $extensao;
        $destino = '../../imagens-advogados/' . $novoNome;

        if (@move_uploaded_file($arquivo_tmp, $destino)) {
            $upload_foto = true;
        } else {
            header('Location: ../admin_advogados.php?erro=6');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: ../admin_advogados.php?erro=5');
    }
} else {
    header('Location: ../admin_advogados.php?erro=4');
}

if ($upload_foto) {

    $DAO = new DAO();

    try {
        $result = $DAO->query("INSERT INTO TB_ADVOGADOS (TXT_NAME, NM_AGE, TXT_DESCRIPTION, TXT_ATUATION, TXT_EXPERIENCE, TXT_GRADUATION, TXT_LANGUAGE, IMG_PATH, TXT_EMAIL, TXT_TEL, TXT_CEL) VALUES (:NAME, :AGE, :DESCRIPTION, :ATUATION, :EXPERIENCE, :GRADUATION, :LANGUAGE, :IMG_PATH, :EMAIL, :TEL, :CEL)", array(":NAME" => $name, ":AGE" => $age, ":DESCRIPTION" => $description, ":ATUATION" => $atuation, ":EXPERIENCE" => $experience, ":GRADUATION" => $graduacao, ":LANGUAGE" => $language, ":IMG_PATH" => $destino, ":EMAIL" => $email, ":TEL" => $tel, ":CEL" => $cel));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if ($result) {
    header('Location: ../admin_advogados.php?success=1');
} else {
    header('Location: ../admin_advogados.php?erro=3');
}
```

Se eu rodar o código exatamente assim, eu caio no seguinte redirecionamento:
`header('Location: ../admin_advogados.php?erro=3');`, que quer dizer que significa que a string não foi mandada pro banco. Porém se remover esse pedaço de código, eu caio na seguinte saida: `header('Location: ../admin_advogados.php?erro=6');`, o que me da certeza que o erro é no armazenamento da imagem.

Alguma ideia do que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fins de ajudar a galera que está com o mesmo problema, vou deixar a solução que achei aqui:

Naveguei até o diretório onde se localiza o meu sistema e utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/caminho/para/o/diretorio/
```

Funcionou bem. Espero ajudar outras pessoas!